# Magento 2 : View all orders on frontend

Tags: magento2, orders, customer

I have a customer group store_admin. If a customer belongs to store_admin, he should be able to view the orders placed by other customers.

I am unable to find out where does Magento check for logged in customer and how does it restrict access.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the class:
`Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History` at the method `getOrders()`   this method is responsible for order collection at frontend customer account page.

If you want to change anything at collection then you have to work `getOrders()`

**For this requirement, you need to override  that class**
Create `di.xml` at `app/code/{Vendorname}/{Modulename}/etc/frontend/`
and  put the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History" type="{Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Sales\Block\Order\History" />
</config>
```

**Rewrite class**

```
<?php


namespace {Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Sales\Block\Order;


class History extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
        array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $orderCollectionFactory, $customerSession, $orderConfig, $data);
    }
    public function getOrders()
    {
        if (!($customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->orders) {
            if($this->_customerSession->getCustomerGroupId() == '{store_admin_GROUP_CODE_ID}')
            {
                $this->orders = $this->getOrderCollectionFactory()->create()->setOrder(
                    'created_at',
                    'desc'
                );
                return $this->orders;
            }else{
                return parent::getOrders();
            }
        }
        return parent::getOrders();

    }
}
```